# Is this CYK parser result correct?

Tags: nlp, compiler-construction, dynamic-programming, chomsky-normal-form, cyk

I am trying to learn the [CYK parsing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm).

For this set of grammar rules, are the resulting tables correct for the two given sentences?

```
S -> NP VP
VP -> VB NP
NP -> DT NN
PP -> IN NP
NP -> NP PP
NP -> NN
VP -> VP PP
IN -> with
NN -> dog
NN -> cat
VB -> ate
NN -> mouse
DT -> the


['S']
[None, None]
[None, None, 'VP']
['NP', None, None, 'NP']
['DT', 'NN', 'VB', 'DT', 'NN']
['the', 'cat', 'ate', 'the', 'dog']


['S']
['NP', None]
['NP', None, 'VP']
['NP', None, None, 'NP']
[None, None, 'VP', None, None]
[None, None, 'VP', None, None, 'PP']
['NP', None, None, 'NP', None, None, 'NP']
['DT', 'NN', 'VB', 'DT', 'NN', 'IN', 'DT', 'NN']
['the', 'cat', 'ate', 'the', 'dog', 'with', 'the', 'cat']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to minimize your grammar first, because there are some unnecessary rules and furthermore that's why it is `not in CNF`.

Looking at it more concisely, you happen to have `None` on the first example, second row, second column. There it is actually possible to have a `S`, but since the logic in CYK cannot do further optimizations such as `NP->NN`. From there `S -> NP VP` for the mentioned `None` cell goes missing. Because of CYK's inability to perform those, **the grammar must be in CNF**. So, basically  it is roughly like you are trying to apply a C-compiler on a C++ programm (with no C++ libraries). And you got *lucky* to even get the right result at the top.

With that being said, I am not going to indulge in the second example of yours.

Just to clarify, a grammar is in `CNF` if it has rules **only** of these two forms:

> S -> AB
>   A -> a

so clearly something like `NP -> NN` is not in CNF.

Comment: ...thanks for answering my question, it's been 4 years and I'm glad I finally got an answer to it, and cleared it up for me. I'm glad I asked that question because I read your answer and it just clicked... Why do you think it's not worth upvoting, could I have asked it better?

Comment: You have not transformed it in `CNF` and the algorithm can't do its job properly, that's why. But after all, this what questions are all about. I am really glad that it cleared itself to you, even though late.

Answer (score 0):

Although the given grammar is not in Chomosky normal form, we can easily convert it to CNF like the following one (e.g., get rid of the illegal production `NP -> NN` and augment the grammar with additional rules):

```
S -> NP VP
S -> NN VP
VP -> VB NP
VP -> VB NN
NP -> DT NN
PP -> IN NP
PP -> IN NN
NP -> NP PP
NP -> NN PP
VP -> VP PP
IN -> with
NN -> dog
NN -> cat
VB -> ate
NN -> mouse
DT -> the
```

With the grammar modified to the above one the DP table with CYK algorithm (refer to the implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921637/cyk-algorithm-implementation/70297170#70297170), although it assumes each symbol in the grammar to be a single character in length, but can easily be extended) will be like the following one, for the first sentence:

[image]

It will have the following parse tree:

[image]

with the 2nd sentence, the following animation shows the DP table generated,

[image]

with the following parse tree:

[image]